# How can I create a write stream for res for a child_process.spawn method as it says cp.spawn().pipe(res) is not a method

Tags: node.js, express, ffmpeg, ytdl

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const cp = require('child_process');
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { v, f, q } = req.query;
    if (!ytdl.validateID(v) && !ytdl.validateURL(v)) {
        return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ success: false, error: 'No valid YouTube Id!' });
    }
    try {
        let info = await ytdl.getInfo(v);

        //set format and title
        // const title = info.videoDetails.title;
        // res.setHeader('Content-disposition', contentDisposition(`${title}${f}`));

        //define audio and video stream seperately and download them
        const audio = ytdl(v, { quality: 'highestaudio' }).on(
            'progress',
            (_, downloaded, total) => {
                console.log({ downloaded, total });
            }
        );
        let format = ytdl.chooseFormat(info.formats, { quality: q });
        const video = ytdl(v, { format }).on('progress', (_, downloaded, total) => {
            console.log({ downloaded, total });
        });

        const ffmpegProcess = cp
            .spawn(
                ffmpeg,
                [
                    // Remove ffmpeg's console spamming
                    '-loglevel',
                    '8',
                    '-hide_banner',
                    // Redirect/Enable progress messages
                    '-progress',
                    'pipe:3',
                    // Set inputs
                    '-i',
                    'pipe:4',
                    '-i',
                    'pipe:5',
                    // Map audio & video from streams
                    '-map',
                    '0:a',
                    '-map',
                    '1:v',
                    // Keep encoding
                    '-c:v',
                    'copy',
                    // Define output file
                    `out.${f}`,
                ],
                {
                    windowsHide: true,
                    stdio: [
                        /* Standard: stdin, stdout, stderr */
                        'inherit',
                        'inherit',
                        'inherit',
                        /* Custom: pipe:3, pipe:4, pipe:5 */
                        'pipe',
                        'pipe',
                        'pipe',
                    ],
                }
            )
            .on('close', () => {
                console.log('done');
            });

        // Link streams
        // FFmpeg creates the transformer streams and we just have to insert / read data
        ffmpegProcess.stdio[3].on('data', (chunk) => {
            // Parse the param=value list returned by ffmpeg
            const lines = chunk.toString().trim().split('\n');
            const args = {};
            for (const l of lines) {
                const [key, value] = l.split('=');
                args[key.trim()] = value.trim();
            }
        });
        audio.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
        video.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[5]);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400);
        console.log('error ', error);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

> I am trying to create a youtube downloader app and this is the code for downloading a video using the ytdl and ffmpeg packages in an express route but i don't know how i can download the result (out.mp4) for the client. when I try to pipe it to res error occurs saying cp.spawn().pipe() is not a method.

Comment: Use `cp.spawn(...).stdout.pipe(res);`

Comment: @HeikoTheißen thanks for the response...although if i write cp.spawn().stdout.pipe(res) then it says "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pipe')"

Comment: I meant `ffmpegProcess.stdout.pipe(res);`

Comment: @HeikoTheißen still the same error :(